I have a persistent 'FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT failed' error with shopping cart app, is it a problem with the models?
So I'm working with a group trying to code a kind of library. We're using django to create the web application, but I keep seeing this error occur.enter image description here
Here's the model I'm using in the cart app:
from django.db import models
from video_rental.models import Movie, CustomUser
from django.conf import settings

class CartItem(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.quantity} x {self.movie.title}'

Here are the views:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import CartItem
from video_rental.models import Movie

def movie_list(request):
    movies = Movie.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'products': movies})

def view_cart(request):
    cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'myapp/cart.html', {'cart_items': cart_items})

def add_to_cart(request, title):
    movie= Movie.objects.get(title=title)
    cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(movie=movie, user=request.user)
    cart_item.quantity += 1
    cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart:view_cart')

def remove_from_cart(request, title):
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(title=title)
    cart_item.delete()
    return redirect('cart:view_cart')


def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')


This persistently happens in the admin panel when I'm trying to add things to a cart and save it. What should I do from here? Movie is defined in the video_rental app so I imported the model from there. I'm wondering what this Foreign Key error and how I can make it work.
I've tried resolving it by correcting the models file, (I realized that the user that was specified in the model was a user that was never defined, so I once again imported the model that was being used in the video_rental app). This didn't seem to work though.

Would try defining models referenced as a foreign key in same video_rental.models file. If video_rental is a separate Django app, that is supported see this post Foreign key from one app into another in Django. Syntax to pass in class.
